# ListView text too long

Tags: java, android, listview

if i add some item which has more than 10 character in its name it display too short that cause the next column not to be readable

This is my .java file

```html
public class listview extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);


        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Orders.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM OrderedList", null);
        ListView a = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] column1 = new String[crs.getCount()];
        double[] column2 = new double[crs.getCount()];
        int[] column3 = new int[crs.getCount()];
        double[] v2 = new double[crs.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        Double sum = 0.0;
        int list_height = 0;
        while (crs.moveToNext()) {
            String item_name = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("Food"));
            double item_price = crs.getDouble(crs.getColumnIndex("Price"));
            int temp_item_quantity = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
            column1[i] = item_name;
            column2[i] = item_price;
            column3[i] = temp_item_quantity;
            v2[i] = column2[i] * column3[i];
            sum += v2[i];
            i++;
        }
        crs.close();
        ListView_Adapter adapter = new ListView_Adapter(this, column1, column2, column3);
        a.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**this is my .xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pop_up_bg">

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have ListView and i want to minimize its text viewing

this is the output after adding item to list

[image]

Comment: post your list item xml

Comment: use `weight` for each `textview`in your `custom listview xml.`

Comment: assign `layout_weight` to all 3 text view..and `weight_sum` to parent ..

Comment: take a look of my xml codes...

Comment: Post your `ListView` Item XML layout

Comment: when you say you want to minimize text viewing. Do you want to limit the number of characters being shown ? or you want to show it in multiple lines?

Comment: i want it to limit the character being showed is it posible?

Comment: The answer will depends on the root `layout` you use for your `ListView` rows, jeiidii. The correct answer for a `LinearLayout` root will not apply to a `RelativeLayout`, for instance, so you will need to post the `layout` `xml` file for your row.

Comment: Yes. You can try also to set android:singleLine = "true"  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: anyone can help me with this?

Comment: im just new in programming so im doing it part by part and one by one

Comment: @jeiidii You will have an `xml` layout file that defines what one of your rows look like in your `ListView`. That's what we need to see to answer your question. If you look inside your custom adapter class, `ListView_Adapter`, you will probably have a `getView()` method. Inside there you will point to the layout file for your row in the following format, `R.layout.*name_of_file*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following parameters to control text view character and line limit.

```
android:maxLines="2" // max number of lines text view can occupy
android:maxLength="50" // number of characters you want to show
android:ellipsize="end" // to show ... at the end
```

My choice of solution for your layout would be.
3 text views in horizontal linear layout. 
With last two text views of fixed width.
and layout_weight of 1 to first text view, with above parameters set according to the need.

Comment: this was helpful but ellipsize didnt show "..." at the end of text ...it just cut like " chick" not "chick..."

Answer (score 3):

### How to overcome from this problem

Please create custom adapter class(like **Array Adapter ,Base Adapter** ) and  set your data in custom layout XML .

Now call this adapter class in your Parent Activity class

In this layout you will set **`Textview width Wrapped and android:ellipsize="end"`** And **`android:singleLine="true"`** . I hope it will helps you.

> android:singleLine="true" Constrains the text to a single horizontally
>   scrolling line instead of letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and
>   advances focus instead of inserting a newline when you press the enter
>   key.

You may check this demo for sample purpose

[Sample Code for ListView with SQLite Database Connection in Android](http://techblogon.com/sample-code-listview-sqlite-database-connection-in-android/)